# Rails 4: simple_form attribute without key-value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

does anyone know how to set an attribute without key-value in rails simple_form?

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :html => "isRequired" %>
```

will generate :

```
 <input html="isRequired" ...
```

what I would like to get is :

```
 <input isRequired ...
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `input_html` instead of `html`:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :input_html => "isRequired" %>
```

Comment: Hello, this will generate `<input input_html="isRequired"...`  :/